# How to use lapply() with aov() because results returns no p-value and f-value but just a list of "Class" and Mode"?

Tags: r, list, lapply, anova

I have this sample data. What I am trying to do  get p values and compare each Person in each dataframe. I tried piping the dataframe list in `kruskal.test()` and it worked but when passing the same data frame using `lapply()` in `aov()`, I am not getting the result. I am sorry I am new to R. I'm just trying to learn how to apply the `lapply()` function in a dataframe list. Another helpful info maybe is that all the values in height and weight columns are means computed from a previous larger dataframes.

```
df_list <- list(
  `1.3.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L

    ),
  `2.2.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,
       "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L
    ), 
  `1.1.B` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L
    )
)
```

I hope someone can make me understand, when using `lapply()` with `kruskal.test()` I was able to get p values, but when I run `aov()` and perform `summary()`, I get a list with no p-values.

this is the output:

```
  Length Class Mode
1.3.A 6     aov   list
2.2.A 6     aov   list
1.1.B 6     aov   list
```

when running and accessing specific dataframe within the list I get a p- and f-value. This code gives me the correct output for the specific dataframe?.
this is the code I use:

```
cary <- aov(df_list[["1.3.A"]]$Height ~ df_list[["1.3.A"]]$Person)
summary(cary)
```

What I don't understand is why does `lapply()` worked differently on these two different tests? Why is it that when I use `lapply()` in `aov()`, it is not working but when I use `aov()` alone accessing a single dataframe, it gives me the expected results?

Failed attempts:

```
mut <- lapply(df_list, function(x) with(x, aov(Height ~ Person, data = x)))
mud <- summary(mut)
mud
```

```
cow <- purrr::map(df_list, ~ aov(Height ~ Person, data = .x))
cow
summary(cow)
```

```
tree <- function(df) {
  aov(Height ~ Person)
}
shrub <- lapply(df_list, tree)
summary(shrub)
```

Comment: Where is your `lapply` code? It's unclear exactly what you are running. Did you use `lapply` for the `summary()` as well? For example: `aovs <- lapply(df_list, function(x) aov(Height~Person, data=x)); lapply(aovs, summary)`

Comment: Apologies, I already edited the post.

Comment: I tried `lapply(aovs, summary)` but still no p-value, but running aov() in individual dataframes returns a proper p-value

Comment: The p-value appears for me. Not sure what you mean. It also looks like `lapply(mut,summary)` returns the p-value. It's not clear what you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry!, `lapply()` totally works on `(aovs, summary)`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your purpose applying those tests.
If code below is your purpose,

```
    cary <- aov(df_list[["1.3.A"]]$Height ~ df_list[["1.3.A"]]$Person)
    summary(cary)
```

and kruskal wallis test that gives you p-value was

```
    lapply(df_list, kruskal.test)
```

then I'm not sure p-value from code above is correct.
That code will print warning message that
In kruskal.test.default(X[[i]], ...) :
some elements of 'x' are not numeric and will be coerced to numeric

This coerced person's name as numeric.
It's pretty messy but code below may be messy but gives better p-values

```
    lapply(df_list, function(x) (kruskal.test(x$Height ~ x$Person)))
    lapply(df_list, function(x) summary(aov(x$Height ~ x$Person)))
```

EDIT:
If you want to get only p-values,

```
    lapply(df_list, function(x) (kruskal.test(x$Height ~ x$Person)$p.value))
    lapply(df_list, function(x) summary(aov(x$Height ~ x$Person))[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[1])
```

will do.

EDIT 2(reply to comments)

1. If you want your tree function work without using $, then you should change code as

   ```
   tree <- function(df) {   aov(Height ~ Person, data = df) }
   ```

or

```
    tree <- function(df) {   aov(df$Height ~ df$Person) }
```

and then, to print p-value, instead of using

```
    summary(shrub)
```

use

```
    lapply(shrub,summary)
```

2. Because I use lapply, it fits ANOVA for each data frame of list.
   To call p-values from summary result, try fitting code below

   ```
    x<-summary(aov(Height~Person, df_list[[1]]))
   ```

then you'll see x is List of 1 and to call components of x and because there is only one element in x, so i call with [[1]]

And then, x has form of matrix so with

```
    x[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`
```

it will print

```
    [1] 1.433592e-42           NA
```

I want to remove NA so i add [1] to the end like

```
    x[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[1]
```

Comment: Thank so much for this! It totally works, but i don;t understand why this works and not `tree <- function(df) {
  aov(Height ~ Person)
}
shrub <- lapply(df_list, tree)
summary(shrub)`

Comment: This is really great, but can you explain this last few codes `[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[1])` I don't quite understand the number. why `1`?

Comment: @TylerRuddenfort Because it's how the structure is built. See the result of `str(summary(aov(...)))` (str shows the structure of an object).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you very much for this explanation. I now understand. I am not familiar with `str()` function.

Comment: I edit above answer. It might help @TylerRuddenfort

Comment: @TylerRuddenfort Note also that in your function you have `aov(Height ~ Person)`, that is, the dataframe is not given as an argument to `aov`, and it's going to be a problem. It should be `aov(Height ~ Person, data = df)`.

Comment: @Park Thank you very much for the clarity of your explanation. This is VERY helpful most especially in understanding the syntax

Comment: Thank you for saying that. I'm glad it helped ^^

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

`summary` is intelligent, it will adapt what kind of summary is shown depending on its input. If the input is the result of `aov`, you will get the p-value, among others. But if the input is a list of aov results, then you will get nothing useful.

```
a <- lapply(list(iris1 = iris, iris2 = iris),
            function(df) aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = df))
 
summary(a)

# Length Class Mode
# iris1 13     aov   list
# iris2 13     aov   list
# 

lapply(a, summary)

# $iris1
#              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
# Species       2  63.21  31.606   119.3 <2e-16 ***
# Residuals   147  38.96   0.265                   
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# $iris2
#              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
# Species       2  63.21  31.606   119.3 <2e-16 ***
# Residuals   147  38.96   0.265                   
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

If, however, the goal is to extract the p-value in order to use it in another computation (that is, not just showing the p-value on screen), then things get a little complicated:

```
str(summary(a[[1]]))

#List of 1
#  $ :Classes ‘anova’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  5 variables:
#   ..$ Df     : num [1:2] 2 147
#   ..$ Sum Sq : num [1:2] 63.2 39
#   ..$ Mean Sq: num [1:2] 31.606 0.265
#   ..$ F value: num [1:2] 119 NA
#   ..$ Pr(>F) : num [1:2] 1.67e-31 NA
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "summary.aov" "listof"
```

That is, it's a list of 1 element, so we first have to get this element with `[[1]]`, then you have to get the 5th element, which is named `Pr(>F)`, and then it's the first element of the resulting vector. Hence:

```
summary(a[[1]])[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[[1]]
# 1.669669e-31
```

Then you can do

```
sapply(a, function(aov.result) summary(aov.result)[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[[1]])
#        iris1        iris2 
# 1.669669e-31 1.669669e-31
```

And to get also the F value:

```
t(sapply(a, function(aov.result) {
  summ <- summary(aov.result)
  c(F = summ[[1]]$`F value`[[1]],
    p = summ[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[[1]])
}))

#              F            p
# iris1 119.2645 1.669669e-31
# iris2 119.2645 1.669669e-31
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. eventually, I will perform a post hoc test and this is what I'm going to try to incorporate in my codes. This is very helpful most especially in understanding the structure and using the p-values for the next tests.